# print only the value of some keys in an array

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I have this source file.

```
[
    {
        "title": "Course1",
        "location": "BuildingA",
        "day": "wednesday",
        "id": 85412
    },
    {
        "title": "Course2",
        "location": "BuidlingB",
        "day": "friday",
        "id": 85413
    },
    {
        "title": "Course3",
        "location": "BuidlingA",
        "day": "friday",
        "id": 85414
    }
]
```

How can I, in PHP, print only the values of the keys 'title' and 'location'?

The code I've got so far is:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($array as $key => $jsons) {
     foreach($jsons as $key => $value)  
echo $value." ";
}
```

Comment: You should read more about arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $jsons) {     
echo $jsons['title'];
echo $jsons['location'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = '
[
    {
        "title": "Course1",
        "location": "BuildingA",
        "day": "wednesday",
        "id": 85412
    },
    {
        "title": "Course2",
        "location": "BuidlingB",
        "day": "friday",
        "id": 85413
    },
    {
        "title": "Course3",
        "location": "BuidlingA",
        "day": "friday",
        "id": 85414
    }
]
';

$array = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($array as $key => $jsons) {
echo $jsons["location"];
echo $jsons["title"];
}
```